# How to bind keyboard keys to clicks on certain positions on screen Mac

Tags: python, macos

I've been trying to bind my up, down, left and right keys on my keyboard to certain clicks on my screen. How would I do that?

I am by the way on a Mac laptop if that matters.

Comment: Questions looking for "some general tips" are usually too broad for SO's approach to specific, answerable questions. This is in part because you should do your initial research [*before* asking here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."

Comment: Also, for an absolute beginner to Python, I personally would recommend doing something that confines itself to text and/or math. You'll get a better foundation for dealing with higher-level projects involving automation, visual geometry, graphical interfaces, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'pynput' module to read keypresses and map them to the functions you want to create using an if statement.
Looks like you want to create hotkeys, refer to this video for a detailed explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n_dfv5DLCGI